# InvalidCastException when trying to obtain UserPrincipal.Current

Tags: powershell, directoryservices

I have a PowerShell script which checks the currently signed in user as part of its start-up process. I'm using .Net to do this by adding the assembly:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
$cUser = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::Current
```

For almost everyone this works fine and I get a UserPrincipal object that I can use elsewhere, however there are a couple of users who get the following error when running it:

```
    Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'. At line:2 char:1
+ [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::Current
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], InvalidCastException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidCastException
```

This is on a standard Windows 10 20H2 install and doesn't matter if PowerShell is running elevated or not. I've never seen this call return anything other than a UserPrincipal before, so I would be grateful for any advice: is this something I can deal with in code, or is there some underlying issue with the machines that are returning this exception?

Comment: Is the affected machine joined to an on-prem AD domain? And, if yes, does the logged on account exist in that domain?

Comment: The devices are all built from MEM, so not domain-joined to AD but we use AD user credentials to log onto them via ADFS. If it wasn't working at all this would be my first thought, but some people seem fine - just a couple that get this error and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Did you recently switch from hybrid-joining to fully MEM-managed perhaps? I strongly suspect this is a clash between expectations made by the authors of the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` assembly and how Microsoft eventually decided to handle hybrud identities on non-domain members

Comment: Yes, until recently these were built by on-premises MECM, but as part of the cloud migration, a lot of the endpoint build/config/management is moving to MEM.

Comment: What happens when you try: `[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::FindByIdentity([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext]::new('Machine'), $Env:Username)`?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for:

```
$cUser = Get-ADUser $Env:Username -Properties *
```

This has the most important attributes that you can use for whatever you want later on. It provides as much attribute as the code you posted that didn't work for some of the user.